# JQuery addClass opacity function fade through images - Solve a Fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This function uses JQuery and UI to fade images through one another in a gallery. I am getting very strange results. On our site it appears the images are not timing themselves correctly and fading seemingly intimitantly.

Anyway I built a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TGgc5/17/

This fiddle does not function at all, ie. nothing happens yet as far as I can see it has all the resources it needs.

Can anyone solve the fiddle
- Images should fade smoothly through each other creating a lovely transition effect.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

UPDATE -  Getting there but still not quite
http://jsfiddle.net/TGgc5/39/

1. Watch the transition between the last slide and the first one. It is static not fading through.
2. When a thumbnail is clicked it needs to perform the function and reset the timer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/7QrbE/

Some mistakes corrected:

- No need to set opacity by changing class, just use `hide`/`fadeIn`/`fadeOut`
- Remember to `clearTimeout` using a global var, or else the timer will override real clicks
- `first()` don't work in this case, just call `'.thumbs.first'`
- had to reformulate the condition of the loop end (checking if the next element don't have the class `thumb`)
- `fadeOut` only the current photo

Final code:

```
$(".cornerimg").hide(); // Hide all images
var slideShowTO, slide; // Global vars

$('.thumbs').click(function() {
    if (slide) $('#P' + slide).fadeOut(2000);
    slide = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#P' + slide).fadeIn(2000);
    clearTimeout(slideShowTO);
    slideShowTO = setTimeout(function() {
        var next = $('#' + slide).next();
        if (next.hasClass('thumbs'))
            next.click();
        else
            $('.thumbs:first').click();

    }, 4000);

});
$('.thumbs:first').click();
```

Comment: Marvellous but a few things. It has to be by adding classes as it will be done via CSS transitions on enabled browsers. I have a fiddle that I put up that almost does what I need -- http://jsfiddle.net/TGgc5/39/ .... 2 problems. Number 1 watch the transition between picture 3 and picture 1. It is not right at all. Number 2, the click function on the thumbnails is not doing anything. It needs to reset the timer.

Comment: @Robin Knight you mean you need the slideshow to stop when you click on any image?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery' UIs addClass() and switchClass() for animation doesn't really work cross-browser in my experience. Theres issues in Firefox not getting quiet to full opacity, and it doesn't work in anything less than IE 9 as they don't support filters  ( scalar values only). In a nutshell it doesnt seem to share the same support as the animate() function. So if you want to use CSS, I suggest you use CSS3 transitions and the [jQuery animateToSelect plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/animatetoselector-jquery-plugin/) as fallback - this plugin isn't perfect as you need to specify the specific rules you want to "extract" from your class but it might help